# TS: Assert function return based on Promise result

Tags: javascript, typescript, assert

**PROBLEM**

Given a function returning a `Promise`,

```js
const fetchSomething = async (): Promise<DocumentType | ServerErrorType> => {
  const data = await fetch(`/data`, {
    method: "get",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  });
  try {
    const res = await data.json();
    return Promise.resolve(res);
  } catch (err) {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
};
```

Called as such,

```js
// TS evaluates both res and err as 'DocumentType | ServerErrorType'
fetchSomething()
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

How can it be asserted and called in a way that if the Promise resolves, the result will be asserted as a `DocumentType`, while if it rejects, then it asserts the result as a `ServerErrorType`?

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Quick and easy solution, is to assert the value directly when calling the function, as followed:

```js
// TS evaluates res as 'DocumentType' and err as 'ServerErrorType'
fetchSomething()
  .then((res as DocumentType) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err as ServerErrorType) => console.log(err))
```

The problem in asserting as such, is I would end up asserting the results of the function anywhere I call it.

**WHAT I TRIED**

I tried asserting the values on `fetchSomething` this way:

```js
try {
  const res = await data.json();
  return Promise.resolve(res as DocumentType);
} catch (err) {
  return Promise.reject(err as ServerErrorType);
}
```

But that doesn't seem to help TS evaluating the correct type.

**CONCLUSIONS**

Is there a clean way of asserting the returned values directly inside that function, based on the Promise result (either resolved or rejected)?

Comment: Just as a side note, there's no purpose served by the `Promise.resolve`, `Promise.reject` or `try`/`catch` in that function's code. The return value of an `async` function is *already* always a native promise, and exceptions are converted to promise rejections. Also, the rejection type shouldn't be in the return type. Finally, the code is falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API (I wrote it up [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)): it doesn't check for HTTP success. Here's what you probably want it to look like: https://pastebin.com/vpWQRu75

Comment: Or if you really wanted to use `ServerErrorType` as the error: https://pastebin.com/4ckx7mEY

Comment: Async functions return a rejected promise when an error occurs in the function. This means that the error in `catch` may not always be a `ServerErrorType`. I recommend *resolving* the promise with `DocumentType | ServerErrorType` instead. However, this would mean you have to handle the errors in `.then` instead of `.catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type annotations on catch variable is currently not supported in Typescript. See [here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20024)

BTW I do recommend changes suggested by @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1):

This promise doesn't work as you expect. Unfortunately, there is no error type supported in Promises - the value of something passed from `Promise.catch` will *always* be typed as `any`. The `T` in `Promise<T>` refers *only* to the value that you would receive if you awaited the promise or if you used `.then`.

In short, what you're trying to do is not possible. All you can really do is set `T` to be the type of the success type and then allow type inference in the catch arm.